# Filter out item in view files using STUFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

this is my view files. I need to filter out the joint_list to joint_list NOT IN('0'). Can anyone help me how to filter out it. Here is the output for the codes. [view files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sBvp.png)

```
 SELECT  CUSTID,SPAID,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(RTrim(user1) AS VARCHAR(Max)) [text()]
 FROM xtcwt_JointAcc(nolock)   
 WHERE CUSTID = t.custid and SPAID = t.SPAID and Status='A'
 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) 
 .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') joint_list  
 FROM xtcwt_JointAcc t with(nolock)  
 GROUP BY CUSTID,SPAID
```

Thank You!!

Comment: `FOR XML PATH` is concatenating the values generated in each row, producing a comma separated string. `STUFF` removes the leading comma and space from the final result. To identify `STUFF` as the important part here demonstrates a strong misunderstanding of the code you're writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your query inside `sub-select/CTE` and filter the `joint_list` outside

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT CUSTID,
               SPAID,
               Stuff((SELECT ', ' + Cast(Rtrim(user1) AS VARCHAR(Max)) [text()]
                      FROM   xtcwt_JointAcc(nolock)
                      WHERE  CUSTID = t.custid
                             AND SPAID = t.SPAID
                             AND Status = 'A'
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ') joint_list
        FROM   xtcwt_JointAcc t WITH(nolock)
        GROUP  BY CUSTID,
                  SPAID) a
WHERE  joint_list <> '0'
```

Comment: thank you so much now i can filter out the joint list but can i know what is the use 'a' after the GROUP  BY CUSTID, SPAID) a?

Comment: @HafifiAli - it is alias name to `sub-select`